# Does SharePoint Online rely on ActiveX in the client?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to specify my organization's OS and browser requirements for an upcoming SharePoint Online implementation.

I can see that [SharePoint 2013 relies on ActiveX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx#activex) and that [64-bit versions of Windows 7 and IE do not support ActiveX](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/i-have-windows-7-64-bit-and-need-to-use-internet/babaa5f8-ff06-4ea2-aef6-a9416d65f981). I also know that SharePoint Online has a limited feature set, but I'm not 100% sure I know every difference between them and I'm new enough to SP (LAMP web developer here) that I'm having trouble interpreting what I can find. (For all I know, this ActiveX stuff is on the server and thus client agnostic.)

So, does anyone know if SharePoint Online relies on ActiveX in the client?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will affect things like Lync presence icons and being able to do things like datasheet view.